Find minimum value of $f(x)= x^{1.5} + x^{-1.5} -4(x + x^{-1})$
Problem: Find minimum value of $f(x)= x^{1.5} + x^{-1.5} -4(x + x^{-1})$
My first attempt involved letting $\lambda = \sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ followed by successive squaring and cubing and then substituting values into question, I solved it. But i don't want to use this method. I want to try it with alternative method
First, I tried to find when $f'(x)$ is $0$ (as the x's that I would get from it would give me minimum value as x approaches 0,function approaches infinite and as x approaches infinite, function also approaches infinite.)
I am getting $f'(x)=\frac{3\sqrt{x}}{2}-4(1-\frac{1}{x^2})-\frac{3}{2x^{5/2}}$ . Further, setting this to zero and solving for x is proving to be a bit of a daunting task for me as I am in 9th grade-- I am not sure how to do that here.
Any help with this method, or any discussion on another method that seems better here are welcome.

Welcome to MathSE.  This MathJax tutorial explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Please type your question rather than posting links to images since links can get broken and users who rely on screen readers may not be able to read an image.

Oh. Sorry, I did not knew it

NF - They're 14 years old and doing calc II. Can you grant them a little humility on not type-setting latex?

@ness NF's comment is not an admonishment, merely advice about the policy of the site.

@VanshChandak Do you know the AM-GM inequality?

@preferred_anon I know AM GM inequality but you can't get answer here by using that.

Apologies for the irrelevant answer, I missed that you wanted to avoid the idea of substituting $(x^{1/2} + x^{-1/2})$. I've deleted the same.

@VanshChandak Probably your original way is the best way to do it.

@VanshChandak, read my answer and, if you like it, you could upvote it.

@Angelo you have a good method. But this method is long. I want ans in max 4 lines. If you have this type of method pls tell me.

set $y=x^{1/2}$ and get $$f(x)=y^3+y^{-3}-4(y^2+y^{-2})$$decompose,get $$f(x)=(y+1/y)(y^2+1/y^2-1)-4(y^2+1/y^2)$$noticed $$(y^2+1/y^2)=(y+1/y)^2-2$$now you can use your $\lambda = y+1/y$ and get$$f=\lambda(\lambda^2-3)-4\lambda^2+8$$$$f'=3\lambda^2-8\lambda^2-3$$the root of $f'$ is  3 and -1/3. $\lambda=x^{1/2}+x^{-1/2}=3$ is the root in the domination. Substitute $\lambda = 3 $ get $f=-10$ ,the minimum value,and now you can solve x easily with the relationship between $\lambda$ and x.

Another way without using derivatives.
I will use the sum of cubes formula and the completing the square method.
$\begin{align}f(x)&=x^{1.5}+x^{-1.5}-4(x+x^{-1})=\\[3pt]&=\left(\sqrt x\right)^3+\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\right)^3-4\left[\left(\sqrt x\right)^2+\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\right)^2\right]=\\[3pt]&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!=\!\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)\!\!\left[\left(\sqrt x\right)^2\!+\!\left(\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)^{\!2}\!\!\!-\!1\right]\!-\!4\!\left[\left(\sqrt x\right)^2\!+\!\left(\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)^{\!2}\right]\!=\\[3pt]&=\!\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)\!\!\left[\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)^{\!2}\!\!\!-\!3\right]\!-\!4\!\left[\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)^{\!2}\!\!-\!2\right]\!=\\[3pt]&=\!\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)\!\!\left[\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)^{\!2}\!\!\!-\!2a\!\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)\!+\!a^2\right]+\\[3pt]&\quad+(2a-4)\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)^{\!2}\!\!-\!\left(a^2\!+\!3\right)\!\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)\!+\!8=\\[3pt]&=\!\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)\!\!\left[\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)^{\!2}\!\!\!-\!2a\!\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)\!+\!a^2\right]+\\[3pt]&\quad+(2a\!-\!4)\!\left[\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)^{\!2}\!\!-\!\dfrac{a^2\!+\!3}{2a\!-\!4}\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)\!\right]\!+\!8\;,\end{align}$
where $\;a\;$ is any real number such that $\;a\neq2\,.$
Now we will look for a real value of $\,a\,$ such that $\;\dfrac{a^2\!+\!3}{2a\!-\!4}=2a\;,\;$ in this way we will be able to complete the factorization by factoring out the greatest common factor.
It is very easy to prove that
$\dfrac{a^2\!+\!3}{2a\!-\!4}=2a\;\iff\;a=3\;\lor\;a=-\dfrac13\;.$
For $\;a=3\;$ we get that
$\begin{align}f(x)&=x^{1.5}+x^{-1.5}-4(x+x^{-1})=\\[3pt]&=\!\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)\!\!\left[\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)^{\!2}\!\!\!-\!6\!\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)\!+\!9\right]+\\[3pt]&\quad+2\!\left[\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)^{\!2}\!\!-\!6\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)\!\right]\!+\!8=\\[3pt]&=\!\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)\!\!\left[\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)^{\!2}\!\!\!-\!6\!\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)\!+\!9\right]+\\[3pt]&\quad+2\!\left[\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)^{\!2}\!\!-\!6\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)\!+\!9\right]\!-\!10=\\[3pt]&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!=\!\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!+\!2\!\right)\!\!\left[\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)^{\!2}\!\!\!-\!6\!\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!\right)\!+\!9\right]\!-\!10=\\[3pt]&=\!\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!+\!2\!\right)\!\left(\!\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!-3\!\right)^{\!2}\!\!-\!10\geqslant-10\end{align}$
for any $\;x>0\,.$
Moreover ,
$f(x)\!=\!-10\iff\sqrt x\!+\!\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\!-3\!=\!0\iff x\!=\!\dfrac{7\!\pm\!3\sqrt5}2\;.$
Hence, the minimum value of
$f(x)=x^{1.5}+x^{-1.5}-4(x+x^{-1})\;$ on the interval $\,]0,+\infty[$
is $\,-10\,$ and it is attained for $\,x\!=\!\dfrac{7\!\pm\!3\sqrt5}2\in\,]0,-\infty[\,.$

The derivative of the function after setting $u=\sqrt x$ turns out to be $$\frac{3 u^6-8 u^5+8 u-3}{2u^5}=\frac{(u-1) (u+1) \left(u^2-3 u+1\right) \left(3 u^2+u+3\right)}{2u^5}$$
The real positive roots are $1$ and $\frac{1}{2} \left(3\pm\sqrt{5}\right)$. Where the value of the function at the $\frac{1}{4} \left(3\pm\sqrt{5}\right)^2$ turns out to be $-10$ and and at $1$ it takes $-6$. The second derivative is positive at the $\frac{1}{4} \left(3\pm\sqrt{5}\right)^2$. The minimum is $-10$.
